# How to fetch a record, checks some properites then update using mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to fetch a record, then checks some properties if true, update the whole record.

I can do `request.something = another` then do `await request.save()`, in this example I can loop the data and save, but I don't think it's a good idea.

I read about mongoose [findOneAndUpdate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html) , but I don't know how to conditionally update.

```
const editRequest = async (user, requestId, data) => {

    let err = new Error()

    if (! requestId) {
        err.code = 404
        err.message = "Request ID is request"
        throw err
    }

    const request = await Request.findById(requestId)

    if (! request) {
        err.code = 404
        err.message = "Request not found"
        throw err
    }

    // database can't have anything but : on, fulfilled, closed, deleted
    if (request.state != "on"){
        err.code = 403
        err.message = "Can't edit a closed/fulfilled request"
        throw err
    }
    
    await Request.findOneAndUpdate({_id: requestId}, data)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
exports.Messages_update = (req, res) => {   Messages.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: req.params.id },
    {
      $set: req.body,
    }   ).then(() => {
    res.send({ message: "Updated Successfully" });   }); };
```

This is how i utilized my findOneAndUpdate() function. By the id parameter of the data entry of the "Messages" collection.

Comment: this isn't what I am trying to do, I am trying to check the Request collection having some record by ID then check the ```state```, if everything is correct I update.
the idea here is that I don't want to call mongoose again to update since I have the doc already as request